# how to fix "Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation."

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to detect and recognize text from an image. I'm implementing different filters to my image. Here's my code and the error. Why I get this error and how can I fix it?

My code:

```
% Load the image.
f = imread('1.png'); [M, N] = size(f);
% High-boost filter
fc = 0.1;
[f1, f2] = freqspace([M N], 'meshgrid');
d = sqrt(f1.^2 + f2.^2);
H_hp_gauss = 1 - exp(-(d.^2)/2/fc^2);
A = 2;
H_hb = (A-1) + H_hp_gauss;
% Image to filter 
F = fft2(double(f));
F = fftshift(F);
G = F .* H_hb;
G = ifftshift(G);
g = ifft2(G); 
g = real(g); 
g = uint8(g);
imshow(g)
```

Error:

```
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in new_script (line 13)
G = F .* H_hb;

Related documentation
```

Comment: The error will be from the two arrays being multiplied not being [compatible](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html). Check their sizes

Comment: Are `f1` and `f2` the same size as `f`? I’d expect them to be, but I don’t see where else the sizes could go wrong.